# Cruise control will not turn on (cannot be enabled nor set)

Tags: electrical, dodge, electronics, cruise-control, stratus

I have a 2006 Dodge Stratus 2.4.  I can't enable cruise control, meaning I cannot turn it on using the switch on the steering wheel. Given that I can't turn it on, I can't set a speed either.

Update: the problem is intermittent; **very rarely** I can press the on/off switch and the cruise control will turn on. If it does turn on, after 3-5 seconds, it turns back off. Setting a speed does not work 99% of the time. If it does get set, the cruise control will turn off again anyway after a few seconds.

Here's what I've checked so far:

- Fuses [All Good]
- Cruise Control Servo [No apparent damage]
- Electrical connection to CC servo [No corrosion and not loose]
- Throttle cable to server [Tension is good and no damage]
- *Will check brake light switch and update*
- *Will check CC switch on steering wheel for corrosion and update*.
- *Will check clock spring and update*

From there, I'm not sure where to go next. Does anyone have any ideas on how to properly troubleshoot my cruise control?

Comment: Check the wiring harnesses leading to the steering column and make sure all the connections are firm and the wires going into the connector are tight.

Comment: There should be a switch on the brake pedal that cancels cruise if you hit the brakes, sometimes they go bad preventing it from turning on.

Comment: Sometimes the switch contacts get corroded, to fix it you need to disassemble the stalk and apply some contact cleaner to the switch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, folks. I'll update the questions with new information once I inspect those items in the garage.

Comment: @Moab wouldn't that switch going bad also cause the brake lights to not engage with the brake? or is it solely for the cruise control?

Comment: any airbag lights? does the horn work?

Comment: @Ben No airbag lights and the horn does work.

Comment: what engine do you have?

Comment: @Moses, no the switch usually has a separate electrical contact for the cruise. Should be easy to test with an ohm meter.

Comment: One possibility is the clock spring behind the steering wheel has failed. This is what connects all the buttons on the steering wheel to the harness.

Comment: @Ben Engine is the 2.4 I4. Same engine as the Sebring of the same series.

Comment: Check button function at the clockspring connector I don't know the resistances offhand but basically each function on the cruise control switch has a different resistance and sends the signal down to the pcm which sends a signal to a solenoid that controls the vacuum reservoir. when no functions of the switch are activated the wire should have full ignition voltage or the wire is open i'm not clear on which it is.

Comment: Although not relevant to this vehicle in particular since it has a drive-by-cable throttle, I just wanted to add that drive-by-wire vehicles operate a little differently. There is no separate cruise control system since everything is being controlled by the computer anyway. All that is required is a couple buttons on the stalk. Which is why even my base model 1999 VW has cruise control, even though it has no AC and manually-controlled everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the brake pedal cancel switch, it may be an integral part of the brake switch but has its own electrical contacts. If it is stuck in the open position this will cause cruise to not engage. You can check this with an ohm meter, pins 3 and 4 (first diagram) should have continuity with the brake pedal at rest, lose continuity when you depress the brake, do this with key off.

[image]

And possibly the cruise switch on the steering wheel column has failed.

[image]

Or the clock spring has failed (behind the steering wheel, this connects all electrical switches on the wheel to the harness)

[image]

Comment: With the clockspring, wouldn't that also prevent the airbag or horn from functioning?

Comment: Depends, I have seen some break where some of the parts still work but not others.